# Floating sections of equal height (CSS Only)

Tags: html, css

I have three floating divs that are supposed to be of same height always. But the height should be the height of the longest floating div. 
I have set up media queries, so this should work in all three cases.

I was unable to use faux columns since I have space between all three sections.
I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75r9mbxn/).`

**I have to do this assignment with float so please don't ask me to remove float and use tables or something. ***

`enter code here`
Please resize the window to see effect of media queries. 
Thanks.

Comment: Ur code is full of errors

Comment: thanks for the heads up.

Comment: :O :O :O :O :O :O

Answer (score 1):

Set `max-height` and `min-height` to elements .I changed your code and now all have the same height

https://jsfiddle.net/75r9mbxn/2/

Update :

https://jsfiddle.net/75r9mbxn/8/

Now it changes based of the highest height of the elements, it changes on load,you can make it change on updating the `section`

Comment: Would you ever use your own suggestion on a project of yours? How can you possibly know that a hardcoded Npx will fit? (BTW your example does not work well. Try resizing a bit. Your height is static therefore the content at some point leaves the DIV boundary)

Comment: The parent height should be dictated by it's content. And the requirement is to keep all the other elements the height of the tallest one - so no. Not a good answer at all and I really don't think you would use that code in your own project.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan What about now

Answer (score 1):

Use [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to calculate the height of the section.
Loop in `section` and compute the max height. Then assign it as the section height.

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$('section').each(function(index, element) {
  var style, height;
  style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  height = parseInt(style.height);
  maxHeight = height >= maxHeight ? height : maxHeight;
});
$('section').css('height', maxHeight + 'px');
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Geethu_Jose/wo8uv0tg/)